# [NSConcreteValue rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try get a range from a string,like:

```
NSString *str  = change[@"new"];
NSLog(@"%@",str);// it will be printed

NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"NSPoint"];//the exception uncaughted
NSLog(@"%lu",range.location);
```

But then i got a exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue
>   rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fc258c4f8f0'

And it puzzled me that if i change the `str`to `@"NSPoint: {0, 0}"`
It will work?! 
Omg, why?

Comment: The error message says that `str` is an `NSValue` object rather than `NSString`

Comment: `change[@"new"]` seems to be a NSValue, not a `NSString` (casting it as you do doesn't change that fact). So `NSValue *value = change[@"new], and NSPoint point = [value pointValue]`?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
NSString *str  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",change[@"new"]];
```

instead of

```
NSString *str  = change[@"new"];
```

Comment: But why? The ```str```is not a  ```NSString```?

Comment: no it is string but you are direct assigning change[@"new"] consider as an id not nsstring so we have to init your str with format.

Comment: welcome and if it is helpful accept my answer. @BJTUzhengli

Comment: That may do the trick, but it doesn't seem to me to be the right solution.